# XPathResult and invalid iterator state

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have a relatively large (500-100 rows) HTML table with a bunch of `<a>` elements.  I would like to add a `<select>` to the top of the page, and populate it by creating an `<option>` for each `<a>` in the table.

My first approach looked something like this:

```
    var initSelect = function () {
        var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
        var items = document.evaluate('//a',  document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

        var item = items.iterateNext();

        while (item) {
            var elem = document.createElement("option");
            var val = document.createAttribute("value");
            val.value = elem.nodeValue;
            elem.setAttributeNode(val);
            elem.innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
            select.appendChild(elem);
            item = items.iterateNext();
        }  
    };
    window.onload = initSelect;
```

As soon as I tried to `appendChild()` to the `<select>` I got an `UncaughtInvalidStateError`.  I figured that modifying the DOM was invalidating my `XPathResult` iterator, so I tried to add all of the `<option>` elements to an array first, and then appending them after iterating through all of the results.

```
    var initSelect = function () {
        var select = document.getElementById('src_select');
        var items = document.evaluate('//a',  document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var elems = [];
        var item = items.iterateNext();

        while (item) {
            var elem = document.createElement("option");
            var val = document.createAttribute("value");
            val.value = elem.nodeValue;
            elem.setAttributeNode(val);
            elem.innerHTML = item.innerHTML; 
            elems.push(elem);
            item = items.iterateNext();
        }  

        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            select.appendChild(elems[i]);
        }
    };
    window.onload = initSelect;
```

If I step through the code in the debugger, I see `items.invalidIteratorState` go to `true` after executing the `elem.innerHTML = item.innerHTML` line.  Then I get the same error on the next call to `items.iterateNext()`.

The first thing I'd like to get working is to just see the `<select>` populated.  After that, the goal is to be able to select an element in the drop down, and have the page navigate to the same link that the corresponding `<a>` element would have taken me to.

This is the first JavaScript I've written, so I appreciate any and all feedback.  At this point, I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution.  Once I get it working I'm going to try to pull JQuery in and revise it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`document.links` gives you all `a href` elements in the document so there is no need to use the XPath API to access those elements. And if you are looking for elements in a particular parent then use e.g. `document.getElementById('foo').getElementsByTagName('a')` to find all `a` elements in that element with `id` attribute being `foo`. I don't see why you would need the DOM Level 3 XPath API for that, which is not supported in IE anyways. And neither `document.links` nor the result of `getElementsByTagName` can be invalidated like an XPath iterator result.

If you really want to use the XPath API then try a snapshot as the result type, it should not fail the way the iterator fails due to document manipulation.